# Creating a simple Django driven online shop engine using Amazon Product Advertising API as backend database

Tags: python, django, database, api, amazon-web-services

Similarly to this sample : https://github.com/evrial/AmazonDjangoShop

I want to create a online shop that using Amazon product advertising api as backend DB.

However, the sample uses django.db as its database.

**How could I switch to use amazon api as the database.** So I don't have to type in the related information of certain products such as price, reviews, and the api does that for me

I have already set up my account and it have linked via my access id and secreat id.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the example briefly and I have this to say: The example does not use Amazon product advertising API as Database Backend. It has sqlite database for storing data. You can see it for yourself if you check out its settings py.

In any case - You can't just use API as database backend. You can use this api for loading products  -sure, but you use it as any other API. Either via django app as proxy, which will make the API calls or using front-end for those calls (if cross domain js is supported by API) with something like angular.js or ember.js.

Comment: Thanks a lot Odif. My goal is to use the api for loading products and display them on a website created by Django. However, I don't know how to use django app as proxy that makes the API calls. Would you mind explaining it more?

Comment: sure thing. You'll have to write some kind of helper which will make api calls via python urllib2 (https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html). Depending on what kind of data api returns (json or xml), you'll have to turn it into something usable and return it from your view. Using urllib2 in views is not the best possible way though. Because this might result in unresponsive views. This is why I suggested you rather use stuff like ember or angular instead of django proxy.

Comment: another way of doing this is to cache the data that is in the api in your own database, so you will not have to wait for urllib2 responses in views.

Comment: Thank you so much. I took a look at ember.js and honestly, I don't know too much about it. Caching the data that is in the api in my own database seems to take less time. Does it mean I can hardcode the requests of the api and just post Whatever I get from the api on the website?

Comment: Yes you can hardcode it, but you probably should do something more dynamic. But for now you can do it any way you want :). You'll learn a lot along the way anyway and will probably redo lot of it later on :)